# Random results when passing byte array from c++ DLL to c# client

Tags: c#, c++, dll, intptr

I am passing a byte array from a function inside c++ DLL to  a c# client.
I am using a widely suggested method IntPtr pointer in C# and then  Marshal.Copy to create byte array in the C# client.
When I read the resulting array it seem I am getting random values. No actual values from the DLL are passed.

It seems the IntPnt is pointing at some random memory address?

Here is the code:

C++ DLL

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char*  __stdcall passBytes() {
    cout << "\n passBytes DLL code START \n";

    char bytes[] = { 0x07, 0x08 };
    cout << "bytes array size: " << sizeof(bytes) << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(bytes); i++) {
        cout << "byte " << i << " = " << (int)bytes[i] << endl;
    }
    
    char* bptr = bytes;
 
    cout << "\n passBytes DLL code END \n";

    return bptr;
}
```

C# client

```
namespace sc_client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            const string libname = "C:/work/x64/Release/libMxN.dll";

            [DllImport(libname)]
           
            static extern IntPtr passBytes();
            IntPtr ptr = passBytes();
            byte[] cbytes = new byte[2];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, cbytes, 0, 2);

            Console.WriteLine("C# client output: ");
            for ( int i = 0; i < cbytes.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("client byte " + i + " = " + (int)cbytes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs ( just relaunched the app 4 times without any modifications in the code)
1.
passBytes DLL code START
bytes array size: 2
byte 0 = 7
byte 1 = 8

passBytes DLL code END

C# client output:
client byte 0 = 176
client byte 1 = 232

2.
passBytes DLL code START
bytes array size: 2
byte 0 = 7
byte 1 = 8

passBytes DLL code END
C# client output:
client byte 0 = 144
client byte 1 = 232

3.
passBytes DLL code START
bytes array size: 2
byte 0 = 7
byte 1 = 8

passBytes DLL code END
C# client output:
client byte 0 = 176
client byte 1 = 228

Comment: char bytes[] in your C++ code is a local variable. It goes out of scope at the function end. You need to allocate it on the heap.

Comment: Well, yes of course you only get random results -- possibly. You declare and create your byte array locally in the C++ function, that means it's allocated on the call stack. As soon as the C++ function returns (exits), the byte array gets out of scope, with the respective call stack space formerly occupied by the array now free to be used/overwritten by other method calls and whatever the .NET runtime fancies to do. So basically, the returned pointer points at some arbitrary location on the call stack that might or might not contain any of your original byte array data anymore...

Comment: You may have an encoding issue.  Display the bytes as a string  From : (int)cbytes[i] To : 
 ("x" + cbytes[i].ToString("X2")).  I added an x to the hex value so result will look like x1F

Comment: As the first comment said, allocate the array on the heap. Then, to free the allocated byte array (which you should do, unless you are a big fan of memory leaks), implement a second C/C++ function in your DLL that receives the array pointer and frees the memory that has been allocated on the heap. Your C# then basically will p/invoke this function in the DLL after it is done with the array...

Comment: Better yet, have the C++ function write its data into a buffer provided by the caller.  This is how 98% of Windows API functions work, and p/invoke works perfectly with it, with no need for `IntPtr` or `Marshal.Copy`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary issue appears to be that the `char*` array is declared locally, and disappears as soon as the function finishes. One way to do this properly is to allocate it on the heap, and make a separate `Free` function.

But you are far better off just passing in a buffer. I'm not familiar with C++ very much, but something like this would be your function

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void  __stdcall passBytes(char* bytes, int size) {
....
```

And then in C# you use it like this

```cs
const string libname = "C:/work/x64/Release/libMxN.dll";

[DllImport(libname)]
static extern void passBytes([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)][Out] byte[] bytes, int size);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] cbytes = new byte[2];
    passBytes(cbytes, cbytes.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("C# client output: ");
    for ( int i = 0; i < cbytes.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("client byte " + i + " = " + (int)cbytes[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, everyone. The local declaration was obviously the problem. ))
I have figured out how to use and pass a buffer declared in the client. So perhaps this will be a preferred way.